# nginx один кэш для множества URL

Tags: nginx, кэширование

Есть вот такие урлы:

```
https://site.com/file_id/some_param/filename.exe
https://site.com/file_id/some_param/file_name.exe
https://site.com/file_id/some_param/name_of_file.exe
https://site.com/file_id/some_param/bada_boom.jpeg
```

Как сделать так что бы кэш был один для разных урлов. У меня есть идея с `proxy_cache_key` но незнаю как изменить `$request_uri` `"$method|$server_name|$request_uri" 〉 "GET|site.com|/file_id/params/"` что бы в ´$request_uri´ не было ничего после последнего `/` в url.

Answer (score 1):

В proxy_cache_key можно использовать переменную вычисленную встроенным perl-ом или, например, lua.

Но. Зачем тебе это? Эти файлы у тебя не статические, не валяются на диске, а формируются для каждого запроса?